# list of lists with week numbers based on date

Tags: python, pandas

I have following problem. I have a data frame with lists of event dates for members.

[image: current format of df]

The events are either signup (=1), checkout (=2), or cancel (=3). If nothing happens in a week it is 0. I want to create separate lists for each member and enter the values for the events that happen in a week. Each week should have its own row and the first week is starting in 2015-01-01.

[image: list I want to achieve]

I would need some help to get the format right. For each user there should be a separate list of lists.

Comment: First step, try to program some code. Second, post a question with especific problem.

Answer (score 0):

With [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) function, you can rotate one list of list as this :

```
[[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9]]
```

change into

```
[[1, 4, 7],
[2, 5, 8],
[3, 6, 9]]
```

with this code :

```
z = zip(MyList)
OutputList = list()
for column in z:
    OutputList.append(column)
```